# Como devo passar um token de autenticação usando o signalR client no Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho um aplicação mobile em flutter que precisa se conectar com um hub signalR que precisa de um toquem de autenticação. No cliente angular eu faço da seguinte forma e funcionana corretamente:

```
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(`${this.apiUrl}chat`, {
                accessTokenFactory: () => userToken
            })
            .build();
```

Usando o client do flutter eu não consigo fazer funcionar.

Tentei com o seguinte código:

```
void buildConnection() {
    String hubUrl = AppSettings.API_URL + "/chat";
    var httpOptions = new HttpConnectionOptions(accessTokenFactory: () { return tokenFactory();});
    this._hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(hubUrl, options: httpOptions).build();
  }
```

O parâmetro **accessTokenFactory** do objeto **HttpConnectionOptions** espera uma `Future<String>`,  então criei uma partir do token armazenado no SharedPreferences:

```
static Future<String> tokenFactory() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return = prefs.getString("token");
  }
```

Aparentemente ele valida o token mas não consegue fazer a conexão, estourando o timeout. A dúvida é estou passando o parâmetro corretamente? Tem alguma forma melhor de fazer isso? Já aumentei o timeout p 15m e mesmo assim não conseguiu estabelecer uma conexão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Cheguei a conclusão que ele valida o token. Pois, se envio um token errado ele retorna erro 401 - perfeito. Testei com um hub sem autorização e conectou de imediato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito de passar o token está correto, mas pode ter sua sintaxe melhorada:

```
    void buildConnection() {
        String hubUrl = AppSettings.API_URL + "/chat";
        var httpOptions = new HttpConnectionOptions(accessTokenFactory: () async => await tokenFactory());
        this._hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(hubUrl, options: httpOptions).build();
      }
```

O problema com o timeout estava realacionado ao protocolo de comunicação, que por default usa **websocket**. É a melhor forma de comunicação, porém o client do flutter não altera o protocolo em caso de falha para uma nova tentativa. No meu caso tive que setar o protocolo LongPolling.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo, o código está correto. Apenas o tráfego de dados usando o protocolo default não funcionou p mim, talvez por algum motivo na rede ou no server que ainda não decobri.